# EC2 Instance Retirement - Just restart or launch new instance from AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, retire

I have received an email about an EC2 instance that is to be retired on the 1/12/2015. I can provide more details on the case if need be. I have gone through this process before (approx a year ago), and it all went smoothly. The only difference this time is in the instructions. Last time, according to the instructions, all I had to do, was just restart my instance. Now, I have to create an AMI from my instance, and launch a new instance with that AMI. Please, note that in both cases my instances were/are EBS backed.

Do I really need to create an AMI and launch a new instance or just restarting the instance would do? Please, keep in mind, that I need to keep my EBS data intact.

Cheers,
Iraklis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [AWS EC2 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-retirement.html):

> Managing Instances Scheduled for Retirement
>
> You can perform one of the actions listed below in order to preserve
>   the data on your retiring instance. It's important that you take this
>   action before the instance retirement date, to prevent unforeseen
>   downtime and data loss.
>
> Warning If your instance store-backed instance passes its retirement
>   date, it's terminated and you cannot recover the instance or any data
>   that was stored on it. Regardless of the root device of your instance,
>   the data on instance store volumes is lost when the instance is
>   retired, even if they are attached to an EBS-backed instance.
>
> An instance is scheduled to be retired when AWS detects irreparable
>   failure of the underlying hardware hosting the instance. When an
>   instance reaches its scheduled retirement date, it is stopped or
>   terminated by AWS. If your instance root device is an Amazon EBS
>   volume, the instance is stopped, and you can start it again at any
>   time. Starting the stopped instance migrates it to new hardware. If
>   your instance root device is an instance store volume, the instance is
>   terminated, and cannot be used again.
>
> **Instance Root Device Type: EBS**
>
> **Action**: Wait for the scheduled retirement date - when the instance is
>   stopped - or stop the instance yourself before the retirement date.
>   You can start the instance again at any time. For more information
>   about stopping and starting your instance, and what to expect when
>   your instance is stopped, such as the effect on public, private and
>   Elastic IP addresses associated with your instance, see [Stop and
>   Start Your
>   Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html).
>
> **Instance Root Device Type: EBS**
>
> **Action**: Create an EBS-backed AMI from your instance, and launch a
>   replacement instance. For more information, see [Creating an Amazon
>   EBS-Backed Linux AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html).
>
> **Instance Root Device Type: Instance store**
>
> **Action**: Create an instance store-backed AMI from your instance using
>   the AMI tools, and launch a replacement instance. For more
>   information, see [Creating an Instance Store-Backed Linux
>   AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-instance-store.html).
>
> **Instance Root Device Type: Instance store**
>
> **Action**: Convert your instance to an EBS-backed instance by
>   transferring your data to an EBS volume, taking a snapshot of the
>   volume, and then creating an AMI from the snapshot. You can launch a
>   replacement instance from your new AMI. For more information, see
>   [Converting your Instance Store-Backed AMI to an Amazon EBS-Backed
>   AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-instance-store.html#Using_ConvertingS3toEBS).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Avihoo. I should had mentioned I am aware of this, and I have gone through the documentation. My main question is why have the instructions in the email changed, not mentioning the plain restart option anymore. That's what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Plain restart won't help any instance scheduled for retirement since it means that the underlying host is probably end-of-life. It means that only stop and start your instance will do the work (in case you have an ebs backed instance) because when you stop and start the instance, it will start the instance on another underlying host, which will resolve the retirement issue since the underlying end-of-life host will be changed.

Comment: Good catch Avihoo. My bad, indeed, by restarting, I meant stop & start.

Comment: From my past experience, stop and start should do the work.

Comment: And you're right Avihoo, I just did that and it all seems to work, plus the retirement event has gone away now. Thank you so much for your help on this!